# cocos2d: scrolling TMXLayer is stuttering

Tags: android, c++, ios, cocos2d-x, tmx

I am scrolling a `TMXLayer` in the background, vertically down. I multiply the distance moved by delta time in the update, so it should be smooth. But it isn't.
Code snippet:

```
void GLayer::update(float delta) {
    //...
    myTMXLayer->setPosition(ccp(0,lastPosition-ammount*delta));
    //...
}
```

Could someone help me to get really smooth scrolling?

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of the problem. If you move the layers slower than the fps, it will stutter. I have 60.0 fps, and I move the layers with 62.0 fps. I'm also casting the new coordinates to int, because I had page tear.